# Problem with debian control file dependencies

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies, debian, packaging

I am creating a package that depends on another. The version number of package 1 is 8.5.2-xxxxxxxxxxxx. I am trying to get package 2 to depend on 8.5.2 and ignore the revision number. It must depend exactly on 8.5.2 but any 8.5.2 revision is fine. Everything I read seems to indicate that I can specify only the version without the revision number for Depends and other settings in the control file but this isn't working. It always says:

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of [product2]:
  [product2] depends on [product1] (= 8.5.2); however:
  Version of [product1] on system is 8.5.2-xxxxxxxxxxxx.

Here my depends line in the control file

Depends: [product1] (=8.5.2)

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine multiple depends on a single package to make a more strict match.

```
Depends: [product1] (>= 8.5.2), [product1] (<< 8.5.3)
```

This is a rather dirty solution though because I believe a version number like 8.5.3~beta1 would still be accepted. An even dirtier solution would be to use `(<< 8.5.3~~)` in that case.

Comment: What does the "~" character mean in this example?

Comment: The way that package version numbers are compared in Debian is handled by `dpkg`. In `dpkg`, the **~** character has been given a value lower than **nul**, flowed by everything else. For example this is the order as seen by `dpkg`: 0.5, 0.9, 1.0~rc1, 1.0~rc2, 1.0, 1.0.1